# Save layout shell/terminal state between sessions

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

So any shell/terminal buffer turns into a text or *scratch* between sessions (if I close and open spacemacs again)

I'm doing TDD and it's quite convenient to have mocha running tests in a vsplit window on the side of a workspace.

What would be the best approach to that?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand.  You're using Spacemacs, in emacs mode, correct?  And you're running mocha tests in an emacs subwindow, correct?  Q:  What OS are you running spacemacs under (in other words, what exactly do you mean by "shell/terminal")? Q: What do you mean by "shell/terminal buffer turns into a text or scratch between sessions"???   What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Good day sir and thank you for your reply. I run spacemacs in vim mode under kubuntu. I created a layout where I have my spec file open and a eshell/multiterm instance loaded (so there are two windows now holding a typescript buffer and a terminal buffer). In the terminal buffer there are tests running constantly.

Now if I quit from spacemacs (let's say the computer needs rebooting) and open it again, I can see all previous layouts restored as well as text file buffers in the layouts, but unfortunately eshell and terminal buffers have turned into empty text buffers called *scratch*.

Comment: Which is not convenient because it means closing them, opening terminal again, bringing it into a proper position/size, cd to the proper dir, run npm test... =\

Comment: This is before https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5PkvCKIQnFIQjhqeXU0eXRINmc

Comment: And this is after restarting spacemacs https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5PkvCKIQnFIRVJidk1EeGpwXzA

Answer (score 1):

You are right. `*shell*` buffer will be reverted into `*scratch*` when you close emacs. (in this case I guessed that you used [desktop.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/desktop.el) to achieve persistent sessions)

Unfortunately dekstop.el doesn't support saving `*shell*` buffers. So it will be reverted to `*scratch*` when you try to save it.

The good news is you can use [desktop+](https://github.com/ffevotte/desktop-plus) which can achieve your needs.
Quoting from documentation

> Desktop sessions by default save only buffers associated to "real" files. Desktop+ >extends this by handling also "special buffers". The list of currently supported s
>   pecial buffer types is:
>
> ```
> - compilation buffers (in `compilation-mode`)
> - terminal buffers (in `term-mode`)
> - org agenda & todo lists (in `org-agenda-mode`)
> - indirect buffers (a.k.a clones).
> - man pages (in `Man-mode`)
> - shell buffers (in `shell-mode`)
> ```

*PS: I don't use spacemacs. According to your explanation, I think spacemacs activate desktop.el by default*